# Type "any" conflicts with function "any" in builtins.pyi

Tags: python, python-typing

When I write `a: any`, Pylance says:

```
Expected class type but received \"(__iterable: Iterable[object], /) -> bool\
```

because builtins.pyi has `def any(__iterable: Iterable[object]) -> bool: ...`.

Any workarounds other than `from typing import Any`?

I'm using Python 3.10.6.

Comment: Don't think `from typing import Any` is a workaround, but the correct way here.  `any` is a built-in function, unrelated to typing.

Comment: Is there a reason you think the builtin `any` function is a suitable type hint? You seem to understand the issue the type checker is telling you about, so I'm not sure what your question is really about.

Comment: Right.  "a: any" is not correct.  It was never intended to work.

Comment: We can use `dict` instead of `Dict` and `from typing import Dict` with the newer version of Python.
My understanding is we can use `any` instead of `Any` like `dict`.
Isn't there a newer version of `Any`?

Comment: No, `Any` from typing is absolutely unrelated to `any` builtin: the former is a type hint, while the latter is a function. Other types are different: `Dict` was introduced as a type hint for `dict` builtin type, same with `list` and `set`. `Type` vs `type` are not 100% compatible too, but it was decided to allow `type[something]` as a type hint. `Any` is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

As @SUTerliakov describes:

> Any from typing is absolutely unrelated to any builtin: the former is a type hint, while the latter is a function. Other types are different: Dict was introduced as a type hint for dict builtin type, same with list and set. Type vs type are not 100% compatible too, but it was decided to allow type[something] as a type hint. Any is not the case.

So I need to use `Any` in my case.